# What happens to videos shot at 60 fps when uploaded to Google+?

Tags: google-plus, video

Does it keep the 60 fps or does it lower it to 30 fps after upload?

Update: YouTube now supports 60fps videos, since Oct'14.

Comment: The best way to know for sure is to try it.

Answer (score 1):

I uploaded a 60fps, 1080p .MTS video to Google+ and the resultant 1080p video appears to be 30fps when playing on Google+.

Having said that, when downloading the original from Google+ it arrives as the original file apparently unaltered.

So Google+ appears to play back a transcoded 30fps version of the video, but it will allow you to download the original 60fps video.